# How to see the columns of my API in PYTHON?

Tags: python, json, api

I'm trying to get the information of this api and then be able to select what are the columns i want to work with. I wrote this:

````
url = "https://ftx.us/api"
data = requests.get(url)
df = pd.read_json(url)
df.head()```
````

Answer (score 0):

`df.columns` 
should do it? It outputs a list of the columns in the data frame.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).